# Undefined variable result while fetching data using laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am new in laravel 5 Now what am I doing here Simply I want to fetch data from the database table `states` where `country_id='101'`. and apply `foreach` loop in my view file but it shows an error i.e. `undefined variable: result`. I don't know why and where I am doing wrong? Please help me.

app/http/controller/FirstController.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use DB;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class FirstController extends Controller
    {
        public function state()
        {
            $sql = DB::select('select * from states where country_id="101"');
            return view('index',['result'=>$sql]);
        }
    }
```

resources/views/index.blade.php

```
<select name="state" class="form-control" id="state">
    <option value="null">India:State</option>
    @foreach($result as $row)
        <option value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

routes/web.php

```
<?php
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('index');
    });
    Route::get('index','FirstController@state');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

Your are calling view `index` without any `result` variable which is giving you this error

First you decide what you want if there is no `result` then do accordingly, to just handle error your can use `$result ?? []`

```
@foreach($result ?? [] as $row)
```

If you want to call same method from two different url `/` and `/index` then use below route

```
Route::get('/','FirstController@state');
Route::get('index','FirstController@state');
```

Also change your query builder to look like more laravel style.

```
    public function state()
    {
        $sql = DB::table('states')->where('country_id',101)->get();
        return view('index',['result'=>$sql]);
    }
```